# Custom iOS Controller for multiple collections

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm still fairly new to the iOS development scene, so I'm not totally sure where to look for open source controls, etc. The app I want to build will have multiple collections in it.  I'd love to have a view where I can swipe up and down to browse between collections, and then swipe left and right to scroll though that particular collection -- all on one screen.

The app I've seen that basically resembles this is the "Popular" screen on the Mobli app for iOS.

I'd be grateful if anyone has seen something similar already built that I could base it on instead of trying to program a new view from scratch w/ my still limited knowledge.

Comment: I'm not sure about any open source implementations of this, but it looks like it's just nested scroll views (or scroll views in table view)...

Comment: or just one scroll view with a little bit smart scroll control function.

Comment: Haven't seen anything like that, but a scroll view with some logic for loading the correct data should take care of that for you.

Comment: Thanks guys. That at least put me in the right direction as far as which terminology to search for. It looks like it's a fairly common question once you know how to properly Google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ScrollView sample project from apple does this, you might want to to take a look at it.

As for reusable components, those are few and far between. It's difficult to protect a XIB in an external library, and beginning developers tend to have trouble getting static libraries to work in their project anyway. Github is where I look for OSS code I can use.

Comment: Except for the up/down scrolling, this sample is a good one. It's enough to get started. Thanks. The sample code is at: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008023-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2